# I am looking for a fantasy romance thriller. It is a series as well

Tags: story-identification, novel

The book was about a girl. I believe she was a ginger with green eyes.

She was always watched over by a demon.

One day she gets a game and she and her friends / boyfriend play it.  They make paper dolls of themselves and then write a fear on the back.

They are then transported into this doll house where they fight their fears and the demon shows himself to the girl he has been protecting.

They go through all the different realms like rooms of this demon's house and he tries to win over this girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Answer (score 2):

The [*Forbidden Game trilogy*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41021-the-forbidden-game) by L.J.Smith.

> He sold her the game, and Jenny Thornton walked out mesmerized by
> Julian, the gorgeous cyber-punk with electric blue eyes and
> frost-white hair. When she and her friends open the plain white box at
> her boyfriend Tom’s birthday party, she chills to the warning:
> “Entering the Shadow World can be deadly. Do so at your own risk.”
> Spellbound, they piece together the rooms with their darkest
> nightmares. Suddenly the game is real! They’re in the house of
> horrors, running from The Shadow Man – Julian himself, who forces them
> to confront their worst nightmares or be lost in a private hell. It’s
> Julian’s game, and Jenny is the prize he’s stalked for years. He’ll do
> anything to win her as she bargains desperately for her body – and
> soul . . .